# Finding certain element using bs4 beautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I usually use selenium but figured I would give bs4 a shot!

I am trying to find this specific text on the website, in the example below I want the last

- 189305014

```
<div class="info_container">
                  <div id="profile_photo">
                    <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/882103883610427393/vLTiH3uR_reasonably_small.jpg" />
                  </div>
                  <table class="profile_info">
                    <tr>
                        <td class="left_column">
                            <p>Twitter User ID:</p>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <p>189305014</p>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
```

Here is the script I am using -

```
TwitterID = soup.find('td',attrs={'class':'left_column'}).text
```

This returns

```
Twitter User ID:
```

Comment: What's your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can search for the next `<p>` tag to tag that contains `"Twitter User ID:"`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


txt = '''<div class="info_container">
                  <div id="profile_photo">
                    <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/882103883610427393/vLTiH3uR_reasonably_small.jpg" />
                  </div>
                  <table class="profile_info">
                    <tr>
                        <td class="left_column">
                            <p>Twitter User ID:</p>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <p>189305014</p>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(txt, 'html.parser')

print(soup.find('p', text='Twitter User ID:').find_next('p'))
```

Prints:

```
<p>189305014</p>
```

---

Or last `<p>` element inside `class="profile_info"`:

```
print(soup.select('.profile_info p')[-1])
```

---

Or first sibling to `class="left_column"`:

```
print(soup.select_one('.left_column + *').text)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code to get you the desired output:

```py
TwitterID = soup.find('td',attrs={'class': None}).text
```

Answer (score 0):

To only get the digits from the second `<p>` tag, you can filter if the string [isdigit()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """<div class="info_container">
                  <div id="profile_photo">
                    <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/882103883610427393/vLTiH3uR_reasonably_small.jpg" />
                  </div>
                  <table class="profile_info">
                    <tr>
                        <td class="left_column">
                            <p>Twitter User ID:</p>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <p>189305014</p>
                        </td>
                    </tr>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

result = ''.join(
    [t for t in soup.find('div', class_='info_container').text if t.isdigit()]
)

print(result)
```

Output:

```
189305014
```